# First index is not integer using foreach loop from 0

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to draw a tree using tikzpicture like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{node}=[circle, fill=blue!25, minimum size=0.1 cm];
    \foreach \ilayer in {0,...,3} {
        \tikzmath {\nnodes = 3 ^ \ilayer; }
        \tikzmath {\leftnum = 1 - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1; }
        \tikzmath {\rightnum = \nnodes - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1; }
        \foreach \isibling in {\leftnum,...,\rightnum} {                
            \tikzmath {\d = 3 ^ (- \ilayer) * 15; }
            \tikzmath {\x = \isibling * \d; }
            \tikzmath {\y = - \ilayer * 2; }
            \node[node] (node_\ilayer_\isibling) at (\x cm, \y cm) {\isibling};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the tree like the following picture. The texts are nodes' `\isibling` within each layer. Most nodes are integers, but all leftmost nodes are not.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just tell Ti*k*Z explicitly that you want an integer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{mynode/.style={circle, fill=blue!25, minimum size=0.1 cm}}
    \foreach \ilayer in {0,...,3} {
        \tikzmath {\nnodes = 3 ^ \ilayer; }
        \tikzmath {\leftnum = int(1 - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1); }
        \tikzmath {\rightnum = \nnodes - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1; }
        \foreach \isibling in {\leftnum,...,\rightnum} {                
            \tikzmath {\d = 3 ^ (- \ilayer) * 15; }
            \tikzmath {\x = \isibling * \d; }
            \tikzmath {\y = - \ilayer * 2; }
            \node[mynode] (node_\ilayer_\isibling) at (\x cm, \y cm) {\isibling};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{mynode/.style={circle, fill=blue!25, minimum size=0.1 cm}}
    \foreach \ilayer in {0,...,3} {
        \tikzmath {int \nnodes,\leftnum,\rightnum;
            \nnodes = 3 ^ \ilayer;
            \leftnum = 1 - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1; 
        \rightnum = \nnodes - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1; }
        \foreach \isibling in {\leftnum,...,\rightnum} {                
            \tikzmath {\d = 3 ^ (- \ilayer) * 15; 
            \x = \isibling * \d; 
            \y = - \ilayer * 2; }
            \node[mynode] (node_\ilayer_\isibling) at (\x cm, \y cm) {\isibling};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In principle you do not need the math library here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{mynode/.style={circle, fill=blue!25, minimum size=0.1 cm}}
    \foreach \ilayer [evaluate=\ilayer as \nnodes using {int(3 ^ \ilayer)},
    evaluate=\nnodes as \leftnum using {int(1 - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1)},
    evaluate=\nnodes as \rightnum using {int(\nnodes - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1)}]
    in {0,...,3} {
        \foreach \isibling 
        [evaluate=\ilayer as \d using {3 ^ (- \ilayer) * 15},
        evaluate=\isibling as \x using {\isibling * \d},
        evaluate=\ilayer as \y using {- \ilayer * 2}]
        in {\leftnum,...,\rightnum} {                
            \node[mynode] (node_\ilayer_\isibling) at (\x cm, \y cm) 
            {\isibling};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally get where the problem starts. Why `1 - floor(\nnodes / 2) - 1` can be non-integer? Even `1 - int(\nnodes / 2) - 1` is  problematic.

Comment: @landings It is due to the way `\foreach` is implemented, internally Ti*k*Z computes with dimensions and this can lead to slight inconsistencies. So it is better to wrap the full expression into `int`.

Answer (score 7):

As @marmot said you do not need `tikzmath` here, but if you use it you can do it in more efficient way :

- You can have a single `\tikzmath` command with loops inside it.
- **You can declare your integer variables as `int` so you do not need to do `int()` afterward.**
- As `\nnodes` is odd you do not need separate `\rightnum` and `\leftnum` as `\rightnum = - \leftnum`;
- Why you use `1-floor(\nnodes/2)-1` in place of `-floor(\nnodes/2)` ?
- The value `\d` can be calculated in the outer loop.
- Instead of using `\x=\isibling*\d` you can say `[x=\d cm]` and then use `\isibling` as`\x`. And in the same way `\y` can be replaced by `\ilayer` using `[y=-2cm]`.

So here is my proposal :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{node}=[circle, fill=blue!25, minimum size=0.1 cm];
  \tikzmath{
    int \ilayer,\nnodes,\rightnum,\isibling;
    \nnodes = 1;
    for \ilayer in {0,...,3}{
      \rightnum = (\nnodes-1)/2;
      \d = 15/\nnodes;
      for \isibling in {-\rightnum,...,\rightnum}{
        {
          \path[x=\d cm,y=-2cm]
            node[node] (node_\ilayer_\isibling) at (\isibling, \ilayer) {\isibling};
        };
      };
      \nnodes = 3*\nnodes;
    };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to LaTeX and need more practice. I didn't know I could loop and draw things just inside tikzmath code.

Comment: Don't worry, even some experts don't know how to use `\tikzmath` ;)